# Simple table expression resulting from CALCULATETABLE function returning error

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

Error: *The expression refers to multiple columns. Multiple columns cannot be converted to a scalar value.*

```
tbExcess Vel OA Lim := 

CALCULATETABLE(
    fWMSL_VibrationsAppended,
    FILTER(
        ALL(fWMSL_VibrationsAppended[Velocity Overall,in/sec]),
        fWMSL_VibrationsAppended[Velocity Overall,in/sec] > 1.25
    )
)
```

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here.

I'm using CALCULATETABLE to filter the original table 'fWMSL_VibrationsAppended' to where column [Velocity Overall,in/sec] is a value greater than 1.25. I'm using FILTER instead of the simpler boolean expression because I'm still learning how DAX works and just trying to drive home the implicit mechanism.

Comment: Is this a measure or a calculated table?

Comment: It is a measure. Now that I think of it, I can't remember if a measure can return a table or not. Couldn't it? How else would you pass a measure into a <tableexpression> parameter?

Comment: I do remember there's a way to visualize a table measure with the EVALUATE keyword...

Comment: Measures have to return a scalar value. You can put this in a calculated table instead.

Comment: That looks like something I can work into the end result. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Measures cannot return a table and must return a scalar value instead. If you want to return a table, you can create a calculated table instead.